# Does Davinci Resolve have a magnetic timeline?

Tags: davinci-resolve, final-cut-pro-x, fcpx

So I just switched from Final Cut Pro to Davinci Resolve. I feel general good since Davinci is more powerful overall. But one thing I do miss is the magnetic timeline. Are there any alternatives in Davinci to get a similar experience to the magnetic timeline in FCP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolve does not have a magnetic timeline, but it does have ripple delete where when you delete a clip it will slide everything over. This is done via the Delete key (not backspace) or ctrl backspace on Windows, and command delete on Mac. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much Logan, I'm on a mac, and I find Shift+Delete will do the trick. I would also like to know if I can make it a default behavior for the Delete key?

Comment: Sure! To do keyboard customization,  click on the 'DaVinci Resolve' menu in the top menu bar, then click 'Keyboard Customization'. You can pretty much bind most functions to any key and additionally see what functions are already bound to certain keys.

Comment: it's fabulous my man! thanks so much! May I ask an additional question: does Davinci have anything like the skimming feature in FCP?

Comment: In DaVinci Resolve there is scrubbing which is basically just dragging the cursor across the timeline and you can turn on audio scrubbing by hitting shift+S. There is also the scrubbing by hovering your mouse over clips in the media pool. If it isn't already on, click on the source viewer menu (3 dots in upper right) and check the Live Media Preview checkbox.

Comment: Thanks so much my man! Is it possible, again, to make scrubbing a default behavior for hovering? (in the edit view) I'm using a trackpad so dragging means three fingers. I still prefer one:)